# Why would VkImageView format differ from the underlying VkImage format?

Tags: imageview, textures, vulkan

[`VkImageCreateInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkImageCreateInfo.html) has the following member:

```
 VkFormat                   format;
```

And [`VkImageViewCreateInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkImageViewCreateInfo.html) has the same member.

What I don't understand why you would ever have a different format in the `VkImageView` from the `VkImage` needed to create it.

I understand some formats [**are compatible with one another**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#formats-compatibility-classes), but I don't know why you would use one of the alternate formats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical use case and primary original motivation (in D3D10, where this idea originated) is using a single image as either `R8G8B8A8_UNORM` or `R8G8B8A8_SRGB` -- either because it holds different content at different times, or because sometimes you want to operate in sRGB-space without linearization.

More generally, it's useful sometimes to have different "types" of content in an image object at different times -- this gives engines a limited form of memory aliasing, and was introduced to graphics APIs several years before full-featured memory aliasing was a thing.

Answer (score 3):

Like a lot of Vulkan, the API is designed to expose what the hardware can do. Memory layout (image) and the interpretation of that memory as data (image view) are different concepts in the hardware, and so the API exposes that. The API exposes it simply because that's how the hardware works and Vulkan is designed to be a thin abstraction; just because the API can do it doesn't mean you need to use it ;)

As you say, in most cases it's not really that useful ...

I think there are some cases where it could be more efficient, for example getting a compute shader to generate integer data for some types of image processing can be more energy efficient than either float computation or manually normalizing integer data to create unorm data. Using aliasing you the compute shader can directly write e.g. `uint8` integers and a fragment shader can read the same data as `unorm8` data

Comment: Concerning your last paragraph, will the fragment shader have to convert from linear to sRGB, etc, manually, or is there another means (except compute transcoder) of converting the image data? This is needed, as you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75876551/7395227) do layout transitions, blitting, etc, with a format other than the one the image was created with.

Comment: Layouts for the aliases needs to be compatible, but other than that "it just works" - just use "the other image view" in the descriptor set for the sampler.

Comment: But if you intend to use the image for other purposes than sampled (blitting, layout transition, etc), you can’t, because its format is now undefined to Vulkan, because Vulkan uses the format it was created with for those operations, not the one you wrote into it with an image view.

Comment: 1:1 transfers don't interpret the pixel content - they just shovel data - so it doesn't matter whether they are sRGB or not.

Comment: That’s not necessarily correct. An image’s data may be arranged differently based on its layout. The number of channels, for instance, may have a role in that, to my best of knowledge. And blitting requires a format, or else it cannot sample correctly.

Comment: Sure, aliasing only works for compatible formats and only for some uses cases. It's not a universal "works everywhere for any format" technique.