# Why does VkImage require extensive format information?

Tags: vulkan

When creating an image with [`vkCreateImage`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCreateImage.html), the image's format must be specified in the [`VkImageCreateInfo`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkImageCreateInfo.html) instance.

The format contains information about the memory requirements of the image. It also contains information about the colour layout (component order), colour space (linear RGB, sRGB, unspecified), and colour conversion methods.

All this data is necessary to use an image in Vulkan. That makes complete sense. On the other hand, certain formats are [compatible with each other](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#formats-compatibility), meaning, their memory requirements are the same, but the other parameters differ.

This can be taken advantage of, by [specifying a different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600143/why-would-vkimageview-format-differ-from-the-underlying-vkimage-format) for the [image's view](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkImageViewCreateInfo.html).

But then why specify the full format of an image (`VkImage`) at all? [`VK_FORMAT`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkFormat.html) contains many more format specifiers than just the memory requirements. Why aren't these separate? They seem to be irrelevant for `VkImage`. Is there any point in considering more than the memory requirements (compatibility class) when picking a format for an image?

Comment: @PaulT. Are you saying I should go read the documentation? The Vulkan documentation is quite extensive, and I may have missed something, but not everything is explained very well there. It's not always very good at reasoning, and due to its size, it can be hard to reason about the API if there's a misunderstanding somewhere. That's why I asked this question here.

Comment: "Why aren't these separate?" That is an example of something the VK documentation will never say in clear text. It's hard to have a definitive answer without the assertions of another human with a better understanding of this topic.

Comment: @PaulT.: "*where the users of such might be more helpful than those here that have likely never heard about vulkan, where the tag info claims nearly 350 questions with NO answers.*" The C++ tag contains 791,211 questions; 100,581 have no answers. That's over 12% unanswered. Vulkan 's 386 unanswered questions of 2114 gives it an 18% unaswered rate. That's not exactly excessive. People who use the [tag:vulkan] tag know what it is, even if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide one example where that info (format, sRGB, etc) is needed to be known by the driver.

**Blitting**

This example is [vkCmdBlitImage](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdBlitImage.html). This function copies an image onto another and, optionally, performs linear filtering.

This function can do format conversion, if the src-dst formats are different (with some restrictions). Obviously, Vulkan can't do format conversion if it doesn't know the formats.

Blitting can also do linear filtering. In the case of sRGB images, the pixels are first converted to linear, then interpolated, and then converted back to sRGB. That is something that can only be done if Vulkan knows that the image is sRGB.

This is just one example, there might be more.

---

**Debuggers**

Specifying the format at image creation allows **debuggers** to display that image correctly to the user :)

---

**Tiling**

Images can be in linear tiling or optimal tiling. Tiling depends on the format. So when you do a layout transition on an image the driver might need to know the format. Actually some tilings are not even supported for some formats.

---

**Difficulty to know the size of some formats**

Usually, R8G8B8 textures use 4 bytes per pixel. But what if some GPU prefers to use only 3?

Some **compressed** formats store indexing tables for blocks. Not easy to know the required size for the whole image.

---

**Format compatibility classes**

Not all formats are [compatible](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#formats-compatibility-classes) between them. If you didn't provide the format, it would not be possible for the driver and validation layers to verify that the formats are compatible.

Comment: Right; I had this false assumption that `vkCmdBlitImage` had a format parameter. But then why doesn’t vkCmdBlitImage require specifying the format, so that one can use an image the same way as with an image view? That makes compositing an image by blitting "impossible", if the image was written to with a format other than the one it was created with, which I assume is what one would do by using a different format in the image view.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess they could have allowed to specify the src&dst formats in vkCmdBlitImage. I don't really know why they designed the API the way they did, maybe it's it's an oversight, maybe it's just for convenience. I will add another use case that just came to mind.

Comment: While the debugger use-case is valid, it doesn't suite the Vulkan mindset, so while it's useful, it could've been specified in the `pNext` chain if it was only needed for debugging purposes. Your answer is useful, but I'm still left wondering why the design is this way. Could the image-view-differing-format case be better handled by recreating the image, but reusing the memory, today? If yes, then why even allow differing formats in the first place? I want to accept your answer, but my doubts haven't been satisfactorily cleared yet. Maybe I need to open another question.

Comment: No worries, leave it like that. Hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on to why it was designed like that. I will, in the meantime, add any others that come to mind.